# re announce a <p> under aria-live even if the text is same

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0, aria-live

I am implementing a search box. One of the scenarios is that the total count of results must be announced. To achieve this I put the `<p>` tag inside of an `aria-live` region, and it announces it as expected.

Expected scenario:

*User types a string --> hits enter --> results appear and string is announced.*

The edge case is if the user hits enter twice.

If the user presses enter again without any changes, nothing is updated since the count is still the same and nothing is announced.

I tried using this on enter click:

```
if (document.getElementById("header")) {
  const currentText: string = document.getElementById("header").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("search-header").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("search-header").innerHTML = currentText;
}
```

But, it still did not announce.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar situation recently. You've already implemented half of the solution (resetting the `innerHTML` to an empty string, then setting it to the `currentText`). The other half of the solution is to set the `aria-relevant` attribute to `all`.

By default the `aria-relevant` attribute is set to `additions text`, but that leaves out the `removed` option. Since you need the screen reader to pickup the change to an empty string (when you remove the text), you need to set the attribute to `all` (which is the same as `additions text removed`).

As a best practice the `aria-relevant` attribute should normally be left alone, but I haven't found another way to get the screen reader to make the same announcement twice.

In your case I would also add the `aria-live` property directly to the element with an `id="search-header"`. It should look something like this:

```
<h6 id="search-header" aria-live="polite" role="status" aria-relevant="all">
  X items found
</h6>
```

You can read more about the `aria-relevant` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-relevant_attribute).

And, there's more information about `aria-live` regions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions#Advanced_live_regions).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I modified the string with the addition of period, in the end, if the same string is added again to the aira-live div.

I compared the new text value with the existing one in  tag, if the value is same then I added period (.) to the incoming string.

```
if (msg == $(".aria-live-div").text()){
    msg = msg + "."
}
```

Comment: This solution utilizes jQuery, but the task and requirements do not include jQuery as a tool. Please modify the solution to use pure JavaScript (vanilla JS) and resubmit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in addition

```js
document.getElementById("search-header").setAttribute('aria-label', text)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).